# Docker-compose can't start apache server

Tags: apache, docker, docker-compose

When i'm running `sudo docker-compose up` inside my dir, i get this error. I'm trying to make a container, that host a php website, where you can do whoami on it.
Thanks

```
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
| no listening sockets available, shutting down
| AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt update

RUN apt install -y apache2 php libapache2-mod-php 

RUN useradd -d /home/cp/ -m -s /bin/nologin cp

WORKDIR /home/cp

COPY source .

USER cp

ENTRYPOINT service apache2 start && /bin/bash
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
   filebrowser:
        build: .
        ports:
            - '8000:80'
        stdin_open: true
        tty: true
        volumes:
            - ./source:/var/www/html
            - ./logs:/var/log/apache2
```

Comment: **[Welcome to StackOverflow! Don't take it seriously if you're downvoted/flagged/edited, it is just stuff that happens. Be calm, and adjust to the community]** Are you running the command to start it without sudo?

Comment: I am running it with sudo:)

Answer (score 1):

There's a long-standing general rule in Unix-like operating systems that only the root user can open "low" ports 0-1023.  Since you're trying to run Apache on the default HTTP port 80, but you're running it as a non-root user, you're getting the "permission denied" error you see.

The absolute easiest answer here is to use a prebuilt image that has PHP and Apache preinstalled.  The [Docker Hub `php` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/) includes a variant of this.  You can use a simpler Dockerfile:

```sh
FROM php:7.4-apache
# Has Apache, mod-php preinstalled and a correct CMD already,
# so the only thing you need to do is
COPY source /var/www/html

# If you want to run as a non-root user, you can specify
RUN useradd -r -U cp
ENV APACHE_RUN_USER cp
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP cp
```

With the matching `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3' # version 2 vs 3 doesn't really matter
services:
  filebrowser:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
    volumes:
      - ./logs:/var/log/apache2
```

If you want to build things up from scratch, the next easiest option would be the Apache [User](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_unixd.html#user) directive: have your container start as root (so it can bind to port 80) but then instruct Apache to switch to the unprivileged user once it's started up.  The standard `php:...-apache` image has an option to do this on its own which I've shown above.